# sub-setting column based on column name in R

Tags: r, subset

I have one data frame with column name as below

```
colnames(Data)
[1] "ID" "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"
```

I wanted to select all columns ahead of column `D`

Currently there are column `E`, `F` and `G`. but I might expect few more column which I am not sure, also I might expect few more columns before `D` as well , so I am not sure about at which location column `D` will be available

Is there any subset command in R we can use? Like below

```
Datanew <- subset(Data,select=c("D","E","F","G"))
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find which column is `D` and select all the following columns (using `ncol`):

```
columnToSelect <- which(names(Data) == "D"):ncol(Data)
Datanew <- subset(Data, select = columnToSelect)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tail` to get the last n names of the data frame once you find where column `D` is.  We can utilize it like this

```
tail(1:5, 3) # return the last three elements
```

The following is equivalent

```
tail(1:5, -2) # don't return the first two elements
```

If we use `which` to find column `D`

```
columnToSelect <- which(names(Data) == "D")
```

We can use `tail` to get all of the columns from `D` and following.

```
tail(names(Data), -(columnToSelect - 1))
```

The column selection, then, can be wrapped up in one neat little call

```
Data[tail(names(Data), -(which(names(Data) == "D") - 1))]
```

A fully reproducible example:

```
Data <- 
  lapply(LETTERS[1:10],
         function(l){
           x <- data.frame(l = rnorm(10))
           names(x) <- l
           x
         })
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)

Data[tail(names(Data), -(which(names(Data) == "D") - 1))]
```